# Prevent HTML Removing Successive spaces

Tags: html, whitespace

I have an issue in a JSP page where I have to display a generated message onscreen based on a string. It all works fine until one of the account numbers contains two spaces.

So, I have this HTML:

```
    <logic:notEqual name="migrationsMessage" value="">
        <div style="color:Red;font-weight:bold">
            <bean:write name="solasDetailsForm" property="migrationsMessage"/>
        </div>
    </logic:notEqual>
```

When the field migrationsMessage contains this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="migrationsMessage" value="A  123456W has migrated to A 123456.">
```

The output on the screen is this:

```
“A 123456W has migrated to A 123456.”
```

The second space after the first A is removed. I tried to alter the style to be this but it didn't help:

```
    <logic:notEqual name="migrationsMessage" value="">
        <div style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;white-space:pre">
            <bean:write name="solasDetailsForm" property="migrationsMessage"/>
        </div>
    </logic:notEqual>
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Try replacing two spaces with space and `&nbsp;`

Comment: The message is actually built in an Oracle DB and passed to the form. If I set both spaces within the DB will they appear as &nbsp; or will the HTML convert them to a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function encodeWhiteSpaces(str) {
   return str.split('').map(function(c) { return c === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : c }).join('');
}
```

The string is converted to an array(`split`), then created a new arrray (`map`) with all white spaces converted to `&nbsp;`, finally join the array back to a string (`join`).

Comment: this is a awesome answer bro. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

`white-space: break-spaces` solved for me. More on white-spaces [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). They have this awesome table:
[image]

Comment: This is a much better method than the old accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces with `&nbsp;` if they're copied/pasted on the front-end they're treated the same as spaces.

Comment: The message is actually built in an Oracle DB and passed to the form. If I set both spaces within the DB will they appear as &nbsp; or will the HTML convert them to a space?

Comment: within the DB they would appear as `&nbsp;` if stored as such, this is a front-end issue, so you should try to keep the solution in the front-end of your project and not pass it onto the DB. in JSP you can do something like `display_id = id.replace(" ","&nbsp;");` and then your `id` will stay clear in the db.

Comment: The actual message is dynamic built up with several keys. The message could be "A  123456W, A 654321T, AE45678F have migrated to A 123456.". Where I change it doesn't really matter. I will try it at the front-end to keep it cleaner though.