# How to stop HTML Form from 'skimping' Spaces

Tags: html, forms, jsp

Basically, I have following problem:

I have a HTML Form with a textfield which has multiple spaces behind each other, yet when submitting the form, they are reduced to one space.

In the textfield, it would have this format:

```
.--  .-
```

But when reading it in, it has this format:

```
.-- .-
```

My problem is that when submitting the TextField, it matters whether there are one, two, three, or however many spaces behind each other.

How can I stop the TextField from automatically reducing the spaces to one?

I am using it in a JSP project, but I don't think that matters. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

EDIT:
I found [this related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706079/prevent-html-removing-successive-spaces), however it has no accepted answer and the only answer given does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

You can use the white-space css property to accomplish this. Something like:

```
<textarea style="white-space: pre"></textarea >
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, it doesn't work on some really old IE and Safari versions, but otherwise compatible with everything.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: break-spaces` solved for me cause I needed to keep the text wrapping. They have this awesome table:
[image]