# Pattern of star in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I have a problem in JavaScript programing. I am beginner and from last 24 hrs I just completed one task that made pyramid star pattern which only work in console but the problem is this, that the same coding doesn't work on browser. In the browser the triangle become  such type of triangle.

I added br to code for the browser but the triangle become  right angle triangle.

Comment: [Prevent HTML Removing Successive spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37706079)

Answer (score 1):

use [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag to render your result, so it doesn't remove extra spaces. most html tag will remove extra spaces because it thinks those are useless.

```js
let starCount = 1;

const row = 35

let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    let starString = "";
    const p = starCount;
    for (let j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        if (j >= ((row - p) / 2) && j < (((row - p) / 2) + p)) {
            starString += "*";
            continue;
        }
        starString += " "
    }
    result += starString + "\n";
    if (row % 2 == 0) {
        if (i < (row / 2) - 1) {
            starCount += 2;
        }
        if (i > ((row / 2) - 1)) {
            starCount -= 2;
        }
    } else {
        if (i < Math.floor(row / 2)) {
            starCount += 2;
        } else {
            starCount -= 2;
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```